# Is there a program or software out there that can trace the sound of something to the image that makes it?

Tags: software

Say an old man is shaking a watch while talking to his daughter and his hand is shaking and you can hear his watch.  Is there a program or software that can deduce the location of the sound and separate it?

Answer (score 1):

A while back I had an idea to do something along those lines. Using computer vision to track the location of a given object or section from an image and have the programme change parameters from a plugin. This way I could automatize certain elements, such as camera whips or footsteps.

As far as I know, there is no such thing out there.

Comment: upon further consideration, that is actually what I was talking about.  I guess technology is not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about spectral analyzation, Adobe Audition and Izotope do this. But my favorite is Cedar Retouch. But as far as automatically finding it, the only thing I have seen is on Sonnox DeNoise and that's mainly for sirens and hums that fluctuate frequency. Not sure if I completely understand your question, though. Let me know if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see how spectrum algorithm determines this and I guess you did answer my question.